# AWSS3GetObjectRequest ifModifiedSince not working

Tags: ios, iphone, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

**Building for** iOS 7+ ,
**Building on** Xcode 6.1 ,
**Using Amazon SDK** AWSiOSSDKv2 2.0.12 ,
**Testing on** iPhone 5s and iPad 2

I am downloading images from my Amazon S3 bucket with the Amazon SDK for iOS.
The downloading is working fine but I want to use the ifModifiedSince property to retrieve only images that have been modified since a certain date
(see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSS3GetObjectRequest.html#//api/name/ifModifiedSince )

However, this is not working. Even when I specify a ifModifiedSince date that is LATER THAN the modified date of the file on S3, the file is returned.

According to the Amazon documentation:
**ifModifiedSince** -

> Return the object only if it has been modified since the specified
>   time, otherwise return a 304 (not modified).

So I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or Amazon has a bug in the SDK.

Here is my code:

```
-(void)downloadPhotoWithName:(NSString*)name completed:(retrievedImage)completed {



NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *cachePaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *cacheDirectory = [cachePaths firstObject];
NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", name];
NSString *filePath = [cacheDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];


AWSS3 *transferManager = [AWSS3 defaultS3];
AWSS3GetObjectRequest *profilePhoto = [[AWSS3GetObjectRequest alloc] init];
profilePhoto.bucket = S3BUCKETNAMEIMAGE;
profilePhoto.key = filename;



if ([manager fileExistsAtPath:filePath isDirectory:NULL]) {

    NSDictionary *att = [manager attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];

    if (att) {

        //Get the date of when the file was modified so we can request to retrieve 
        //the file only if it was modified SINCE that date

        NSDate *modifiedDate = [att objectForKey:NSFileModificationDate];

        if (modifiedDate) {
            profilePhoto.ifModifiedSince = modifiedDate;
        }

    }


}


[[transferManager getObject:profilePhoto] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {


    //If it was working we should get a 304 not the image file
    if (task.result) {


        AWSS3GetObjectOutput *output = (AWSS3GetObjectOutput*)task.result;
        NSData *imageData = (NSData*)output.body;


        if (imageData) {


            NSDictionary* attr = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:output.lastModified, NSFileModificationDate, NULL];

            //The log confirms that the date I am passing for ifModifiedSince is LATER THAN
            //the last modified date of the file on S3
            //but the the image file is returned anyway.. is it a problem with Amazon ?

            NSLog(@"output.lastModified: %@\nmodifiedDate: %@", output.lastModified, profilePhoto.ifModifiedSince);

            if  ([manager createFileAtPath:filePath contents:imageData attributes:attr]) {

                 completed(imageData);

            }
            else {

                NSLog(@"Could not save image to disk for some reason");
                completed(nil);

            }



        }
        else {



            completed(nil);
        }



    }
    else if (task.error) {
       NSLog(@"DownloadPhotoError: %@", task.error);

       completed(nil);
    }



    return nil;
}];

}
```

Comment: Can you capture your actual http request headers?

Comment: I can reproduce this.  Investigating ....

Comment: It might be a bug. Waiting for confirmation

Comment: `If-Modified-Since` is currently formatted as `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'` where it should be `EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z`. S3 uses `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'` as the date format, but `If-Modified-Since` is a part of HTTP specifications and needs to be formatted differently. We are working on a fix, and the next update should address this bug. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. we shall await the next update.

Comment: @Yosuke Matsuda any updates ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've released the AWS Mobile SDK for iOS 2.0.14. It should address the time formatting issue.

Comment: I have tested this and can confirm that it now works.

Comment: ifModifiedSince is not working for me in SDK version 2.4.7. Can any one help me