# AWSS3GetObjectRequest.ifModifiedSince does not seem to be working

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm not able to get ifModifiedSince to work.  Here is my code:

```
func updateDatabase()
{
    let objectRequest = AWSS3GetObjectRequest()
    objectRequest?.key = "wa/wa2016/idahoGmu.tiff"
    objectRequest?.bucket = bucketName

    let dateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    dateComponents.day = 10
    dateComponents.month = 4
    dateComponents.year = 2018
    let date = NSCalendar.current.date(from: dateComponents as DateComponents)

    // TODO This isn't working.  It grabs the file regardless of date.
    objectRequest?.ifModifiedSince = date

    let s3 = AWSS3.default()

    s3.getObject(objectRequest!).continueWith
    {
        (task) -> AnyObject! in if let error = task.error
        {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        if let result = task.result
        {
            let fileManager = FileManager.default
            let documents = Bundle.main.resourcePath
            let writePath = documents?.appending("/Content/idahoGmu.tiff")
            let output = result as AWSS3GetObjectOutput

            let fileData = output.body as! Data
            fileManager.createFile(atPath: writePath!, contents: fileData, attributes: nil)
        }

        return nil;
    }
}
```

Is there something I am doing wrong with formatting the date?  I read this issue about the date format (but it is reported as fixed now):
[AWSS3GetObjectRequest ifModifiedSince not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27190654/awss3getobjectrequest-ifmodifiedsince-not-working)

When I print out the date it looks like this:

2018-04-10 07:00:00 +0000

Comment: Download an object and take a look at the `Last-Modified` header.  That's your format.

Comment: OK, this is from the object I downloaded:

Comment: contentLength = 435278;
contentType = "image/tiff";
lastModified = "2017-03-14 19:46:29 +0000";

But the ifModifiedSince field I pass in is a date object (see dateComponents variable above).  Since it is an object, the date doesn't really have a format that I can control.  What am I missing?

Comment: A little more info ... Here is the ifModifiedSince date in the request:
`"If-Modified-Since" = "Fri, 10 Apr 2020 07:00:00 GMT"`
Here is the lastModified in the object returned:
`lastModified = "2017-03-14 19:46:29 +0000"`
How do I control the format of the date in the request (since it is an object, not a string)?

Comment: @Yosuke Matsuda do you have any insights on this?

Comment: Have you tried with a date that is NOT in the future.  I know that an apache server will ignore If-Modified-Since that are later than the server's own current time, perhaps Amazon is doing the same.

Comment: Just tried with a date that is NOT in the future.  I used "2017-05-10 04:14:59 +0000" for ifModifiedSince.  The file on S3 has "2017-04-19 19:41:01 +0000" for lastModified.  It still downloaded the file, so still not working correctly.  But that was a good idea to try.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe do you can replace `ifModifiedSince` to `AWSS3HeadObjectRequest()`, for example:

```
// create a date to compare
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
let checkDate = formatter.date(from: "2016/10/08")

// make a request to AWS S3, to get a info of file
let request = AWSS3HeadObjectRequest()!
request.bucket = bucket
request.key = key
AWSS3.default().headObject(request).continue({
    task -> Any? in

    if let result = task.result,
      ((result as AWSS3HeadObjectOutput) != nil) {

        let servDate = result.lastModified!
        if checkDate < servDate {
            // my file was modified after 2016/10/08
        } else {
            // my file was NOT modified after 2016/10/08
        }
    }
 }
```

[You can see a example where.](https://github.com/brunomacabeusbr/RuAWSS3/blob/master/RuAWSS3/Classes/AmazonS3.swift) I use something similar to create a cache system, in `checkDownloadCache(bucket:key)` function.

Comment: Yes, that is what I have resorted to - comparing the dates myself.  But I would still like to know why ifModifiedSince is not working on the AWSS3GetObjectRequest.  I did try formatting the date using DateFormatter, so it looks like "2018-04-10 07:00:00 +0000", to match the format that comes back from AWS.  But getObject still gets the object regardless of the date.  Thanks for your example.